# Representation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with unit square

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that we can represent the projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the unit square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with opposite sides in the opposite orientations. I'm having trouble seeing why this is the case.

I'm wondering if anyone can walk me through the geometric construction of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ from the unit square.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What definition are you using for $\mathbb{R}P^2$? Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane help? Or https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/a-few-of-my-favorite-spaces-the-real-projective-plane/? Can you ask a more precise question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that $\mathbb{RP}^2 $ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2 / \sim_{[0,1]^2}$, where the equivalence relation $\sim_{[0,1]^2}$ identifies opposite boundary points on the square, i.e.
$$ (t, 0) \sim_{[0,1]^2} (1-t, 1) \text{  for all } t \in [0,1], \qquad (0, s) \sim_{[0,1]^2} (1, 1-s) \text{  for all } s \in [0,1].$$

---

First, observe that the square $[0,1]^2$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk $D = \{ (x, y) : \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 1 \}$.

An explicit homeomorphism $\phi : [0, 1]^2 \to D$ is given by
$$ \phi(x, y) = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x - 1/2\right)^2 + \left(y - 1/2\right)^2}} \left(x - \tfrac 1 2, y - \tfrac 1 2\right).$$

Furthermore, for any $(x, y), (x', y') \in [0, 1]^2$, we have
$$ (x, y) \sim_{[0,1]^2} (x', y') \iff \phi(x, y) \sim_D \phi(x', y'),$$
where $\sim_D$ is the equivalence relation on $D$ that identifies opposite boundary points on the disk, i.e.
$$ (\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \sim_D (-\cos\phi, -\sin\phi) \text{ for all } \phi \in [0, 2\pi).$$

Thus the homeomorphism $\phi : [0, 1]^2 \to D$ gives rise to a homeomorphism on quotient spaces, $\overline\phi : ([0, 1]^2 / \sim_{[0,1]^2}) \to (D / \sim_D)$.

---

All that remains is to show that $\mathbb {RP}^2$ is homeomorphic to $ D / \sim_D$.

Consider the continuous function $\psi : \mathbb R^3 - \{ (0, 0, 0) \} \to D / \sim_D$, defined by
$$ \psi(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} \left[ + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} (x, y) \right]_{\sim_D} & \text{if } z \geq 0 \\ \left[ - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} (x, y) \right]_{\sim_D} & \text{if } z \leq 0\end{cases} .$$
In words, this function $\psi$ is a composition of the following maps:

- The identity map (if $z \geq 0$), or the inversion map (if $z \leq 0$).
- A rescaling to unit norm.
- A projection onto the $(x, y)$-plane. (The image will necessarily lie inside the unit disk $D$.)
- Identification of opposite boundary points on $D$ (as per the equivalence relation $\sim_D$).

Notice that for the case where $z = 0$, our definition of $\psi$ provides two expressions for $\psi(x, y, z)$. We should check that these two expressions are consistent with one another. Indeed, when $z = 0$,  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} (x, y)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (x, y)$, which lies on the boundary of $D$. Furthermore, $+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (x, y)$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (x, y)$ are identified via the equivalence relation $\sim_D$. So the two expressions are consistent with one another.

Having checked that $\psi$ is well-defined, we can argue that $\psi$ is continuous as claimed: $\psi$ is continuous on the closed sets defined by $z \geq 0$ and $z \leq 0$, so by the Gluing lemma, $\psi$ must be continuous on the whole of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{ (0, 0, 0) \}$.

It is easy to see that
$$ \psi(x,y,z) = \psi(x', y', z') \iff (x, y,z) \sim (x',y',z'),$$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$ that identifies points that are equal to a rescaling, i.e.
$$ (x, y, z) \sim (x', y', z') \iff (x,y,z) = \lambda (x', y', z') \text{ for some } \lambda \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}.$$

It is even easier to see that $\psi$ is surjective.

Thus $\psi$ gives rise to a homeomorphism $\overline\psi : (\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{ (0, 0, 0) \} / \sim) \to (D / \sim_D)$.

But $ \mathbb R^3 \setminus \{ (0, 0, 0) \} / \sim$ is $\mathbb {RP}^2$, so we're done.